# How to easily view source code of a package/command?

Tags: macros, packages, code, sourcecode, ctan

Is there a command that directly leads me to the source of a package or command? For example something like

```
$ texinfo viewsource amsmath
```

that shows me the code of `amsmath` or

```
$ texinfo viewsource equation
```

that shows me the code of the `equation` environment. Sometimes I find neat packages with commands that I would like to override or customize but do not come with PDF documentation on CTAN.

Comment: Try `more $(kpsewhich amsmath.sty)` (for a package) and `latexdef equation` (for an environment or a macro).

Comment: This doesn't work at each time. For example, `latexdef NiceTabular` fails (the package `NiceMatrix` proposes this environment). This sounds like a missing feature rather than a bug.

Comment: @projetmbc you need to tell `latexdef` which package provides the macro with the `-p` switch, here `latexdef -p nicematrix NiceTabular`. This means you cannot use the tool to find out which package provides a command or environment, but once you know the package then you can view the source of any command.

Comment: @Marijn  I plead guilty : `latexdef --help`. :-) Thanks for the option.